# insert or update on table violated foreign key constraint (error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a polymorphic association of `User` and `AuthorizedReceiver` using `PersonalInfo`.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :authorized_receivers
  has_one :personal_info, as: :info_owner
end

class AuthorizedReceiver < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :personal_info, as: :info_owner
end

class PersonalInfo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :info_owner, polymorphic: true
end
```

When I create my first `AuthorizedReceiver` to the user, and try to update  the `PersonalInfo` of this `AuthorizedReceiver`, I have success. However, when I create the second `AuthorizedReceiver` and try to update its `PersonalInfo`, I have the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "personal_infos" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_796da13f22"
DETAIL:  Key (info_owner_id)=(2) is not present in table "users".
: INSERT INTO "personal_infos" ("info_owner_id", "full_name", "created_at", "updated_at", "info_owner_type") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS: The same doesn't happens if I do the same with `User` (i.e, try to update the `PersonalInfo` of a second user succeed).

EDIT:

```
class CreatePersonalInfos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def up
    create_table :personal_infos do |t|
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true, index: true, unique: true
  end
end


class AddInfoOwnerToPersonalInfos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def up
    rename_column :personal_infos, :user_id, :info_owner_id
    add_column :personal_infos, :info_owner_type, :string

    add_index :personal_infos, [ :info_owner_type, :info_owner_id]

    PersonalInfo.update_all(info_owner_type: 'User')

    change_column :personal_infos, :info_owner_type, :string, null: false
  end

  def down
    rename_column :personal_infos, :info_owner_id, :user_id
    remove_column :personal_infos, :info_owner_type
  end
end
```

That resulted in a wrong fk constraint that still pointing to users:

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY public.personal_infos
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_rails_796da13f22 FOREIGN KEY (info_owner_id) REFERENCES public.users(id);
```

Comment: Do you have a record in `users` with a `info_owner_id` of `2`?

Comment: @eurotrash no. In this test described, I have only one `User` and two `AuthorizedReceiver`.

Comment: Well it's telling you exactly what the issue is then, right?

Comment: But why it acuses this error in `User`, once that this `PersonalInfo` belongs to `AuthorizedReceiver`? The `info_owner_type` of the record itself says that belongs to `AuthorizedReceiver`

Comment: Take a look into `db/schema.rb` and you will find `foreign key` from `personal_infos.info_owner_id` to `users.id`

Comment: You're right @PavelMikhailyuk ! I found this: `ALTER TABLE ONLY public.personal_infos
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_rails_796da13f22 FOREIGN KEY (info_owner_id) REFERENCES public.users(id);`, it's pointing to users. What happens is that `PersonalInfo` became polymorphic, but it wasn't at the beggining, I created first with this `t.references :user, foreign_key: true, index: true, unique: true`. You know how can I update this constraint?

Comment: Please also post the migrations used to create these 3 tables, probably you'll find out that you created personal_infos.info_owner_id as reference to users instead of a polymorphic reference

Comment: Updated the question with relevant extra info about migration @AndreDurao . You know how can I update this constraint safely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like both me and @PavelMikhailyuk commented:

you just renamed the column to `info_owner_id`

```
rename_column :personal_infos, :user_id, :info_owner_id
```

You also need to remove the foreign key:

Since you changed the column name, Rails may not find the association automatically, then you may try to remove the foreign_key with a migration like this:

```
remove_foreign_key :personal_infos, column: :info_owner_id
```